# Polynomials such that $P(X)\mid P(X^2)$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I just found this problem in an old email but I have forgotten how to do it.

> Find the number of monic irreducible polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $P(X) \mid P\left(X^2\right)$ and $\deg(P) = 144$.

Comment: $X$ and $X-1$ are examples

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The problem is about such polynomials with degree 144.

Comment: ... only for odd $n$.  For example, $n=292$ does not work even though $\phi(292)=144$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $r$ is a root of $P(X)$, it must also be a root of $P(X^2)$, which says $r^2$ is a root of $P(X)$.  Thus squaring maps the set of roots of $P(X)$ into  itself.  This implies that all roots of $P(X)$ must be either $0$ or roots of unity.  $P(X)$ is either $X$ or a cyclotomic polynomial.  Moreover, you can show that only cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_j(X)$ with odd $j$ work.  Now, what odd $j$ have $\Phi_j(X)$ of degree $144$?

Comment: Why is it that only odd $j$ work? Using your other observations, I could bruteforce the answer: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdT9EKgzAMfBf8h7wMWycyZU8D_0F8VEREqyt0aeh01L9fqwy2XV4uJLnLVVBAXTeRjdowsK6p0lkg42HgaxQTPLV6CUb8FgbgoNxO0x580gYQJILpcRYsS4DlMfE4zuEM2efCQ04gViVMR3fJkENRAH2NPUonPGyD0ot-yKEjrTZ0rFcME7D8d9nplcw6Iw4nz3bFy5_i_m7aEwkcnekxNGJZDYLy8chIXNgRMLteOX8D8eRAtw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Comment: A root $r$ of $\Phi_j(X)$ is a primitive $j$'th root of unity.  If $j$ is even, $(r^2)^{j/2} = 1$, so $r^2$ is a primitive $(j/2)$'th root of unity, not $j$'th.

Comment: Oh and when j is odd, 2 is invertible modulo so $r^2$ is still primitive. Nice!

Comment: Here is a simpler solution that computes the answer: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjsEKgzAQRO9C_mFuJrYIiqdCfsKjIkVwtYGwLlGLn99IEPrmssPMwrSw6Lo-P_NBZWc0bbkQa6OySxPN2Fb_JS3mpTJEfOz0Q7rnNYDhGGHkhXT1hK4LMUVR44Ho6vvpws2gw1N4y8dpNrAW8hff-HIUIZ5iJYWB9iMw_LVHguNdp0VV0xjzA7yfLa4=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==